# how to write a pip requirements file such that it does not install beta versions?

Tags: dependencies, versioning, pip

Right this moment, if you do a `pip install nose-cov==1.6` you will get the following packages installed:

```
cov-core==1.7
coverage==3.6b1
nose==1.2.1
nose-cov==1.6
```

Unfortunately, the package `coverage` seems to be a beta version and is a bit buggy, failing coverage tests when in fact I have 100% coverage. This is especially troublesome when I have a requirements.txt file with a bunch of packages listed, each of which could potentially start downloading beta versions of their own requirements in the future.

Is there a way to tell `pip` to avoid beta versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is not possible currently. I have been forced to hard-specify versions for packages that tend to publish betas on pypi.